# How can I use infinite-scroll in combination with mat-table and service in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am having trouble using `infinite-scroll` within my `mat-table`. I get the data with the `table.service.ts` class from the backend. How can I use the Infinite scroll functionality within my spreadsheet so that more and more content is automatically displayed when I scroll down.

Window - Angular 7. I use Material Table.

liste.component.ts

```js
private load() {
    const liste_sub = this.liste_Service.loadListe('001', 0, LIST_SIZE).subscribe(
      liste=> {
        this.dataSource.data = liste;
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // onError()-Rumpf
        this.handleHttpError(err);
      });
    this.subscription.add(liste_sub);
  }
```

liste.service.ts

```js
  public loadListe(from: number, size: number): Observable<Liste[]> {
    if (!this.cache$ || this.from_cashe$ !== from || this.size_cashe$ !== size) {
      this.from_cashe$ = from;
      this.size_cashe$ = size;
      this.cache$ = this.doRequest(from, size).pipe(
        shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
      );
    }
    return this.cache$;
  }

  private doRequest(from: number, size: number): Observable<Liste[]> {
    const params  = new HttpParams().append('from', from.toString()).append('size', size.toString());
    const url = this.API_URL.replace(':vertragsnummer', vertragsnummer);
    const httpOptions = { headers, params };
    return this.httpClient.get<Liste[]>(url, httpOptions);
  }
```

liste.component.html

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
....

</table>
```

I would like to add virtual scrolling into my table. It should load as much contents as the size of the page. If the user is scrolling down it should load and show further contents. In that case the die page is getting longer. The scrollbar should not be shown inside the table. So no additional scrollbar.

Comment: Check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-data-table-infinite-scroll

Comment: Thanks. Thats it :) could u explain me, what "scrollDelay=3000" and "scrollOffset" do? and how can i use MatProgressSpinnerModule?

Answer (score 9):

I hope [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1vg9gn?file=app/table-basic-example.ts) would help you.

Infinite scrolling isnt working well with mat-table, though it can be achieved without using the infinite scroll module or cdk-virtual-scrolling.

To read more about this
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9858

Answer (score 6):

Infinite scroll and virtual scroll are different things.

To achieve VirtualScroll you need fixed height items and you can use the materialCDK: https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

To achieve InfinityScroll I recommend you to use Intersection Observers: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: For people that don't know: VirtualScroll DOM renders only the rows that fit on the screen no matter how bit the data source is. InfiniteScroll just renders more data when you reach the end of the rendered data